# Django company structure reflected on database

Tags: database, django-models, orm

I am having trouble finding a away to create a database model that reflects a company structure. What I’d like to do is when a user registers an account to be able to register as a single person or a company manager. If the person is a company manager he could then create new users and divide them into departments where each user will have his own credentials to be able to login. What I am struggling with is how to setup the different models

I have managed to create a basic user account for login